# How to return value from linq in method?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

Can you give me sollution about my source code about return linq in my method. My source code like this:

```
 public  int GetRole(string user, string pass)
    {
        TAEntities db = new TAEntities();
        var Hasil = from u in db.User
                    join r in db.Role
                    on u.id_Role equals r.id_Role
                    where u.userName == user && u.password == pass
                    select r.id_Role;

        return Hasil;
    }
```

My source code still false. and then, I am update my source code now :

```
public  int GetRole(string user, string pass)
    {
        Tugas_AkhirEntities db = new Tugas_AkhirEntities();
        var Hasil = from u in db.User
                    join r in db.Role
                    on u.id_Role equals r.id_Role
                    where u.userName == user && u.password == pass
                    select r.id_Role;

        return Hasil.FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

and i add this source code to check my value save in variable hasil or not.

```
 if (model.GetRole(model.UserName,model.Password) == 1)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        else
            return RedirectToAction("Contact", "Home");
```

can you give me more solution about it?

Comment: What is the problem you're seeing with the code? Does it fail to compile? Does it throw an exception? Does it return the wrong value? Tell us what the problem is so we can help you.

Comment: Also, once we finish fixing your problem, I feel obligated to point out that your code is a HUGE SECURITY HOLE waiting to be hacked.

Comment: You've edited the question, but I still don't know what "source code is false" means. Does it compile? Feel free to answer here in the comments section.

Comment: sorry, this source code only example. And you can read again for my problem in this source code.  I ask about how to return value from this method. NOT SECURITY!!!

Comment: As I mentioned in the third comment, your question is still unclear. Does it compile?

Comment: @DanTeesdale that's right. It's about join in linq. can you give me solution?

Comment: No problem @AvnerShahar-Kashtan. Can you give me solution now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Hasil` is an `IEnumerable<int>` or an `IQueryable<int>` and your method returns an `int`. You need to select one of the values using `First`, `FirstOrDefault`, `Single` or `SingleOrDefault` e.g.

```
return Hasil.First();
```

Alternatively, change the return type of your method to `IEnumerable<int>` or `IQueryable<int>`.